# Finding the centroid of an xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray that represents boolean (e.g., forest/no forest) geospatial data with the dimensions x, y representing latitude and longitude, and I want the centroid coordinates.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
A = xr.DataArray(np.array([[0,0,1,1,0,0],
                           [0,1,1,1,0,0],
                           [0,1,1,1,0,0],
                           [0,1,1,0,0,0],
                           [0,0,0,0,1,0]]),
                 dims=['y','x'],
                 coords={'x': [10,20,30,40,50,60],
                         'y': [50,40,30,20,10]})
```

I came up with the following solution:

```
centr_x = float(np.sum(A.sum('y')/np.sum(A.sum('y')) * A.x))
centr_y = float(np.sum(A.sum('x')/np.sum(A.sum('x')) * A.y))
```

Just wondering if I'm missing a function in `xarray` that does just this? It seems to me that this would be a rather common thing to calculate.

Thank you for suggestions!

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you do not want to use extra modules?

Comment: Which ones do you suggest? I found solutions for centroids of polygons but nothing for raster data. Also the next step in my program is to extract some parameters from my data into a pandas dataframe, and there is no more geospatial analysis after that.

Comment: Well, since I am not aware of your project's directions, I think I am not qualified to suggest anything, and I am no expert in using `xarray`. But, In this case, I prefer using `geopandas` and `shapely`.

Comment: `shapely` would be for polygons, but `geopandas` could be a good suggestion - I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I suggested `shapely` because it can be useful in order to make a polygon and find its centroid(I am not sure if it is what you want, anyway!).

Comment: shapely doesn't just support polygons - the geospatial operations in geopandas use a shapely backend (or a cython port of shapely operations). but yeah either seems like a fine approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in xarray that interprets raster data as geometries or point collections, or to calculate the centroid of such features.

Your approach is clever - you could certainly use weighted averaging to get a simple centroid, e.g.:

```py
In [8]: A.x.weighted(A).mean()
Out[8]:
<xarray.DataArray 'x' ()>
array(31.81818182)

In [9]: A.y.weighted(A).mean()
Out[9]:
<xarray.DataArray 'y' ()>
array(32.72727273)
```

You could also do this using geometries/points using shapely. To do this, you can convert the raster data into a series of points:

```py
In [4]: points = A.where(A).to_series().dropna()

In [5]: points
Out[5]:
y   x
50  30    1.0
    40    1.0
40  20    1.0
    30    1.0
    40    1.0
30  20    1.0
    30    1.0
    40    1.0
20  20    1.0
    30    1.0
10  50    1.0
dtype: float64

In [6]: points = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(list(zip(
   ...:     points.index.get_level_values('x'),
   ...:     points.index.get_level_values('y'),
   ...: )))

In [7]: points
Out[7]: <shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint at 0x1050b76a0>
```

then you can use shapely tools to calculate the centroid:

```py
In [8]: points.centroid
Out[8]: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1533fada0>

In [9]: points.centroid.xy
Out[9]: (array('d', [31.818181818181817]), array('d', [32.72727272727273]))
```

Note that if your data corresponds to geospatial coordinates you may want to compute the centroid within an equal area projection. A similar xarray-based approach would require converting the lat/lon coordinates to an equal-area projection:

```py
In [10]: xx, yy = np.meshgrid(A.x, A.y)

In [11]: points = gpd.points_from_xy(
    ...:     xx.ravel(), yy.ravel(), crs='epsg:4326'
    ...: )

In [12]: equal_area_xy = points.to_crs('+proj=cea')

In [13]: A.coords["equal_area_y"] = (
    ...:     ("y", "x"), equal_area_xy.y.reshape(A.shape)
    ...: )

In [14]: A.coords["equal_area_x"] = (
    ...:     ("y", "x"), equal_area_xy.x.reshape(A.shape)
    ...: )

In [15]: A
Out[15]:
<xarray.DataArray (y: 5, x: 6)>
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
Coordinates:
  * x             (x) int64 10 20 30 40 50 60
  * y             (y) int64 50 40 30 20 10
    equal_area_y  (y, x) float64 4.866e+06 4.866e+06 ... 1.1e+06
    equal_area_x  (y, x) float64 1.113e+06 2.226e+06 ... 6.679e+06
```

Now you can use the same weighted averaging method to calculate the centroid:

```py
In [16]: equal_area_centroid_y = A.equal_area_y.weighted(A).mean()

In [17]: equal_area_centroid_x = A.equal_area_x.weighted(A).mean()

In [18]: centroid = gpd.points_from_xy(
    ...:     [equal_area_centroid_x],
    ...:     [equal_area_centroid_y],
    ...:     crs="+proj=cea",
    ...: ).to_crs("epsg:4326")

In [19]: centroid.x, centroid.y
Out[19]: (array([31.81818182]), array([31.94714021]))
```

Note that the latitude is meaningfully lower in the version we round-tripped through the equal-area projection - this accounts for the fact that distances between lines of longitude are smaller at higher latitudes so the centroid will be somewhat lower when correctly accounting for this curvature. This is of course still approximating the shape of the earth as a sphere - a more precise centroid would require a much more complex workflow.

Comment: lots of very useful stuff in your answer! I suspect conversion to multipoints will be slow for my large datasets - will get some timing and report back

Comment: yeah so in that case I'd definitely recommend the xarray approaches and convert the indices rather than the points. the weighted averaging returns the same results!